# CRM 2011 How to migrate record from a custom entity into Contacts

Tags: merge, entity, move, crm

I am currently working on a solution for Dynamics CRM and I need to remove all of my records from a custom entity (Prospects) and into the Contacts entity. Is there any way I can do this programmatically?

I can't figure out a solution and I do not want to have to move them all manually 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, however if you are creating a new Contact entity for each custom Prospect entity, you can do this using the built-in workflow feature.  Depending on the number of fields on your custom entity it may be a lengthy process though.  However once done it will make short work of your migration.

Comment: I actually managed to resolve this, since I asked this question 5 months ago with no response.

Comment: I realize this was an old post, however there were zero answers at the time.  I thought an answer might help others in the same situation.